# Can somebody help me proofread a sentence

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

"After long accumulation(a long period), they will gradually form a habit, which is to be dependent on the charity given by the rich."

How to say that properly in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

> They will gradually form a habit of dependence on charity given by the rich.

**Explanation:**

The meaning of "After long accumulation" and "(a long period)" are both essentially contained in "gradually" - i.e. that it will take time, rather than being instantaneous. We don't want to say the same thing three times, so I chopped that off.

Side note, here - "accumulation" means "build up over time", and probably wouldn't be appropriate here. You could talk about dust accumulating in an attic, for example.

> ...they will gradually form a habit, which is to be...

This grammar is incorrect. You'd use a comma followed by "which is" to *define* a word. For example, "He contracted HIV, *which is* a disease affecting the immune system". When explaining that people have a specific habit, you use "of", as in "I *have a habit of* correcting people's English".